# No TNS Listener when using SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

We use SQL*Loader for bulk loading, and we have written a shell script to do this.

When I execute the script I am getting this error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production 

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor


Enter user-name: SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
Enter user-name: ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

I'm able to log-in to the database using SQL Developer. So the user and password combination is not a problem.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the line in the shell script where you call the loader (without the password, of course)?

Comment: Additionally, do you have access to the database server, in other words, can you put the files somewhere the oracle server can read them?

Comment: Yes I'm able to put the files into the database server.

Comment: The sample shell file is as below,

sqlplus -S $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$SID    <<EOF
spool something.log


Drop table  Name cascade constraints;

CREATE TABLE "Name"
  (
    "ID"   INTEGER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "Age" INTEGER,
    "Type"   VARCHAR(5),
    "Name" VARCHAR(15),
 "Sex" CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT "NAME_ID" PRIMARY KEY (""ID") ENABLE
  );

Comment: OK, thanks! I would try the following steps from the unix command line (replacing mysid with the real value of the ORACLE_SID etc): 1) tnsping mysid 2) sqlplus myuser/mypass@mysid 3) sqlplus $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$SID. If that doesn't work, please write back...

Comment: As you can put the files on the server, I'd use external tables instead of SQL*Loader. Much easier, much faster, much more stable, much more fun. They are described in the Utilities guide right after SQL*Loader: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#i1009391  If you have questions, just ask ahead...